# Select TOP 1 doesnt return value in case of ex-aequo

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, correlated-subquery

this is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk8n5b0xxwim30d/stack%20overflow%20data.txt?dl=0) to my data.

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl c
WHERE C.dep = (select top 1 dep
                       from tbl cc
                       where cc.yea = c.yea
                       and cc.mon = mon
                       group by mon, yea, dep, n
                       order by n desc)
        OR C.dep =(     select top 1 dep
                                from tbl cc
                                where cc.yea = c.yea
                                and cc.mon = mon
                                group by mon, yea, dep, n
                                order by n asc 
                                )
ORDER BY yea, mon, n
```

that sould return for each `(month,year)` the best (lowest n) and the worst (highest n) `dep`. This query works for month 1,2,4,5,7 and not for months 3,6. The only difference is that in both 3 and 6 cases I got two del with same score (1). How can I return one of them, instead of not returning anything.

this is my output:

```
n           yea        mon        dep
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           2017        1           50
48          2017        1           36
58          2017        2           36
85          2017        3           36
1           2017        4           50
39          2017        4           36
1           2017        5           50
39          2017        5           36
19          2017        6           36
3           2017        7           50
17          2017        7           36
```

And this is how I expected:

```
n           yea.        mon         dep
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           2017        1           50
48          2017        1           36
58          2017        2           36
85          2017        3           36
1           2017        3           49 (or 67)
1           2017        4           50
39          2017        4           36
1           2017        5           50
39          2017        5           36
1           2017        6           50 (or 13)
19          2017        6           36
3           2017        7           50
17          2017        7           36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by yea, mon order by n asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by yea, mon order by n desc) as seqnum_desc
      from tbl t
     ) t
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```